# Is there an Angualr 8 equivalent to Angular 1 $filter('orderBy')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am new to angular , want to know the equivalent to `$filter('orderBy')` used in angularJS controller.

AngularJS code:

`$scope.itemsSorted  = $filter('orderBy')($scope.newFilteredData, 'page_index');`

Comment: There is no equivalent. You have to code it manually in TS.

Comment: What do you want to filter ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe):

> Angular doesn't provide pipes for filtering or sorting lists. Developers familiar with 
>   AngularJS know these as filter and orderBy. There are no equivalents in Angular.
>
> The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself.

You could use the standard [Javascript `sort` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) like this inside your component:

```ts
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.source$.subscribe(data => {
        this.sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => a.pageIndex - b.pageIndex);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone.
I found the solution and works fine.

```
let itemsSorted = this.newFilteredData.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.page_index - b.page_index;
});
```